# Convert RGB image to YUV and convert back in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-conversion

I am very new to Matlab. I am trying to convert an RGB image to YUV, and convert it back to RGB. This is my code:

```
RGB = imread('ist.jpg');

R = RGB(:,:,1);
G = RGB(:,:,2);
B = RGB(:,:,3);

Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B;
U = -0.14713 * R - 0.28886 * G + 0.436 * B;
V = 0.615 * R - 0.51499 * G - 0.10001 * B;

R = Y + 1.139834576 * V;
G = Y -.3946460533 * U -.58060 * V;
B = Y + 2.032111938 * U;

RGB = cat(3,R,G,B);
imshow(RGB);
```

The final image that Matlab shows me is very blue-ish and very different from the initial RGB image. Also when I compare the certain pixels before and after Blue channel values, I get different values then each other. What am I doing wrong.

Also if there is a more efficient and shorter way to let me access an image's Y, U and V values, it would be better.

I would be really thankful for any help of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have MATLAB access any more so can't test this.  However, `imread` is most likely returning `uint8` data.  Do `whos` and see what the data type is.  If it is `uint8`, the RGB->YUV->RGB conversion is clipping.  Try this:

```
RGB = double(imread('ist.jpg'));   % convert to double

% RGB->YUV->RGB like you have them in the current code    

RGB = cat(3,R,G,B)./255;    % since it's a double now, need 0..1 range for imshow.
                            % Divide 0..255 by 255 to get 0..1.
imshow(RGB);
```

See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/88934) for more discussion of `imshow` and data types.

Comment: Thanks, it did the magic. It was a very rookie mistake I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions in the Image Processing Toolbox to do that: `ycbcr2rgb` and `rgb2ycbcr`.